# ASP.net Web Services versus WCF

Tags: wcf, web-services

A .net desktop application will send information to a central server, there will be potentially thousands and thousands of deskop apps sending info to my server(s).

The data will be small in size.

Would .net web services be good for this scenerio or would WCF be better suited?

What are the pros/cons?

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with a WCF REST-based service, because you'll be able to transmit pure data without the overhead of the SOAP header (and other envelope nonsense) that comes with the SOAP-based classic .asmx web service.

Answer (score 2):

the possibilities for throttling, concurrency, etc. are far more developed within wcf. 
its a little bit more work in the beginning, but i guess that it's better suited for scenarios where you need to have full control over your bindings.

Answer (score 2):

WCF is a more robust approach to SOA. Microsoft is committed to making it the primary framework for building the next wave of Microsoft business applications. The functionality available already, early in its lifecycle, is superior to plain old web services. It's only going to get better. By going with WCF early, you will be able to ride the wave and take advantage of future new functionality.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases depends on the type and amount of data to send.
WCF will give you more options to tweak your calls.

On the other hand, I can't think of advantages of implementing asp.net web services over WCF. In WCF you could also implement plain 'old' web services

Answer (score 0):

ASMX is like remoting, it's still around because it shipped with 1.0, but you shouldn't use it anymore if you are starting a new project. WCF will give you many more features and better tooling support.

Comment: There's a huge difference between web services and remoting.

Comment: His point was that like remoting, the .asmx way is considered deprecated and that you should start using WCF.