# Web Services vs WCF , advantage and disadvantages 

Tags: wcf, web-services, comparison

I want to clear my doubts about some questions related to web services and WCF.
Following are my doubts..

1. What is the message format in Web Services , like in WCF every message is a SOAP message?
2. Can we use TCP/IP protocol in Web Services if not then why not ?
3. Why we use DataContractSerializer in WCF while we already had XMLSerializer,SOAP      Serializer,BinarySerializer  in .Net Framework?
4. When i create a wcf service and define endpoints even when i don't add IMetadaExchange endpoint, i just add service behavior and say `httpGetEnabled = true`, why it's possible to create a proxy class by using `AddServiceReference` , i mean how can someone access my service details untill i don't expose `mex` endpoint.

Please help me out in clearing my doubts in above questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- [What is the difference between the Visual Studio Options: ASP.NET Web Service and WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773621/what-is-the-difference-between-the-visual-studio-options-asp-net-web-service-and)
- [Web Services -- WCF vs. ASMX ("Standard")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666/web-services-wcf-vs-standard)
- [WCF v.s. legacy ASP.Net Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164938/wcf-v-s-legacy-asp-net-web-services)
- [What is the difference between an asp.net web method and a wcf service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216931/what-is-the-difference-between-an-asp-net-web-method-and-a-wcf-service)
- [Web Service vs WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351334/web-service-vs-wcf-service)
- [what is the difference between wcf service and web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862489/what-is-the-difference-between-wcf-service-and-web-service)
- [ASP.net Web Services versus WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208492/asp-net-web-services-versus-wcf)

Answer (score 1):

WCF is an umbrella technology that covers a lot of *communication* topics. WCF can used to communicate with Web Services, with other WCF applications, with MSMQ applications and more. You can replace the endpoints used to switch from a SOAP based HTTP channel to a binary TCP based one. Even more, you can do this at deployment time, changing only the .config file (some restrictions apply).

So some specific answers:

1. WCF *can* use SOAP messages
2. WebServices were always TCP/IP. HTTP is TCP/IP.
3. DataContractSerializer provides **versioning**. The most important thing in distributed apps.
4. I'll let some WCF expert answer that.